# How do I get binary equivalent string of a given uint512_t integer

Tags: c++, integer

I'm using a [boost/multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) `uint512_t` and I've tried using bitset library but it wont work for big integers like `uint512_t`. How can I convert it?

This is what I've tried with no success

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main(){
        uint512_t num("11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758400790883467166");     
        std::string binNum = std::bitset<512>(num).to_string();        
        
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but questions of the form "*Is there a library that..*" are off-topic on SO. It's also unclear what you mean by "string of bytes". A hex string perhaps?

Comment: Not a hex of strings, rather something like bin() from python?

Comment: Your code does not compile, since there are no integers as large as the one you're passing to the `num` constructor.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Forgot to put it in " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but I couldn't find any, so here goes.

You can use a bit mask to extract bit-by-bit and put it in a `bitset<512>`.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    uint512_t num("11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758400790883467166");
    std::bitset<512> b;

    size_t idx = 0;
    while(num) {                   // loop for as long as "num" isn't zero
        b[idx++] = (num & 1) != 0; // check the least significant bit
        num >>= 1;                 // shift down by one
    }

    // print the result
    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100101111111111111111111111110011110
```

Comment: Also see [Importing and Exporting Data to and from `cpp_int` and `cpp_bin_float`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html) - It could provide a better answer, but as I said, I couldn't work it out.